# Convertir un DateTime a String php

Tags: php, sql, datetime

Tengo el siguiente método para hallar el intervalo de tiempo de una hora a otra:

```
public function calcular_duracion($id)
{
    $consulta = $this->db->prepare('SELECT inicio, fin FROM reunion WHERE ID=:id');
    $consulta->bindValue('id', $id);
    $consulta->execute();
    $reunion = $consulta->fetch();
    $reunionRecuperado = new Reunion();
    $inicioR = $reunionRecuperado->setInicio($reunion['inicio']);
    $finR = $reunionRecuperado->setFin($reunion['fin']);
    $inicio=$reunionRecuperado->getInicio($inicioR);
    $fin=$reunionRecuperado->getFin($finR);

    //Línea159
    $inicio = date_format($inicio, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $fin = date_format($fin, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

    list($horas, $minutos) = explode(':', $inicio);
    $hora_en_minutos_inicio = ($horas * 60) + $minutos;

    list($horas, $minutos) = explode(':', $fin);
    $hora_en_minutos_fin = ($horas * 60) + $minutos;  

    $duracion = $hora_en_minutos_fin - $hora_en_minutos_inicio;

    return $duracion;
}
```

}

Y me devuelve el siguiente error:

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in model/reunionDAO.php on line 159.

Parece que el problema está en el formato delos parámetros que le paso al date_format(), pero es que en la documentación pone que es así. No sé qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal...

Comment: No, el problema estaba en que le estaba dando un formato en string a una fecha que ya lo era (línea 159 y siguiente). 
Esas dos líneas sobran y todo correcto. Publico respuesta!! Gracias por la ayuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function calcular_duracion($id)
{
    $consulta = $this->db->prepare('SELECT inicio, fin FROM reunion WHERE ID=:id');
    $consulta->bindValue('id', $id);
    $consulta->execute();
    $reunion = $consulta->fetch();
    $reunionRecuperado = new Reunion();
    $inicioR = $reunionRecuperado->setInicio($reunion['inicio']);
    $finR = $reunionRecuperado->setFin($reunion['fin']);
    $inicio=$reunionRecuperado->getInicio($inicioR);
    $fin=$reunionRecuperado->getFin($finR);

    list($horas, $minutos) = explode(':', $inicio);
    $hora_en_minutos_inicio = ($horas * 60) + $minutos;

    list($horas, $minutos) = explode(':', $fin);
    $hora_en_minutos_fin = ($horas * 60) + $minutos;  

    $duracion = $hora_en_minutos_fin - $hora_en_minutos_inicio;

    return $duracion;
}
```

Y así obtengo la duración como un entero y puedo operar con ella.